# How to Call a javascript function every 15 sec, for 5 mins only and how to check page is idle for some time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have written this function which calls automatically every 15 secs each.

```
setInterval(
  function () {
    check_alive_status();
  }, 
  15000 // every 15 seconds
);
```

Now my requirement is, i have to run this function only for first 5 minutes, and afterwords it should not be called. How can i achieve it? Any way there?

I need to check if any background processes like any ajax call or a file upload happening in that web page also. If nothing is running and the page is idle, then after 15 min, i have to logout the user. How to check that also?
Thank You!

Comment: you don't need a function inside. `setInterval(check_alive_status, ...)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
// do something every 15 sec

var myVar = setInterval(function(){
 // do stuff here 
}, 15000);

// cancel after 5 min

setTimeout(myStopFunction, 5 * 60 * 1000)

// clears the interval

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please help me with that?

Comment: the way i usually do something like that is using sessions, you logout the user after the session ends, and when he makes a request it throws him out, or you could make a poll request every few minutes or seconds (not recommended) to check if the user is logged in